# What is the bound for $L_{\infty}$ norm for positive part of exponential sum?

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, exponential-sums

A famous conjecture posed by Littlewood and solved by O. McGehee, L. Pigno, and B. Smith(in their article, Hardy's inequality and the $L_1$-norm of
exponential sums) and S. V. Konyagin independently is the following inequality,

> Littlewood conjecture in exponential sum, for $A\subset \mathbb{N^*}$, $|b_i|=1, \forall i$, we have an absolute constant $C$ do not relate to $A$ only related to $|A|$, such that.
> $$\|\sum_{a_i\in A}b_ie(a_i\theta)\|_1\geq C\log|A|$$
> Where $e(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$ .

This is done by finding a $L_2$ paring $hf_A$ of $f_A=\sum_{a_i\in A}e(a_i\theta)$ which is $\|\|_{\infty}$ bounded and very closed to a "decay version"(to make the square meaningful) of $\sum_{a_i\in A}e(a_i\theta)$ in the $L_2$ space, then we can directly calculate the norm of the paring $<hf_A,f_A>$ and get the estimate.

As pointed out by Bloom and Lewko, the $L^2$ norm and general $L^p$ norm is elementary, the problem will focus on $f_{A+}$.

> Problem. Define $f_{+}=f\cdot \chi_{\{x|Re(f(x))>0\}}$, $f_{A+}=(\sum_{a_i\in A}b_ie(a_i\theta))_+$, is there potential to make this method also make sense to estimate $L^{\infty}$ norm for
> $$\inf_{A\subset \mathbb{N^*}, |A|=n}\|f_{A+} \|_{\infty}=\inf_{A\subset \mathbb{N^*}, |A|=n}\|(\sum_{a_i\in A}b_ie(a_i\theta))_+\|_{\infty}\ \ \ ?$$
> $e(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$.
> Or we can get the estimate maybe without this constructing pairing method?(The point is whether such a good estimate already existed).

> Remark. $\mathbb{T}$ is compact so it is easy to use rearrangement inequality( and maybe use symmetrization to make thing clear) to show for $1<p\leq \infty$,
> $$\|\sum_{a_i\in A}e(a_i\theta)\|_p\geq\|\sum_{a_i\in A}e(a_i\theta)\|_1\geq C\log|A|$$
> So we expect some estimate stronger than $O(\log|A|)$.
> And by pointed out, $\|\sum_{a_i\in A}e(a_i\theta)\|_2=\sqrt{|A|}$, and more general $\|\sum_{a_i\in A}e(a_i\theta)\|_{2k}$ can be estimated by iterating use squaring and then expanding argument change to a problem bounding additive energy of a fixed finite set.

Comment: The $L^2$ norm is always trivially $=\lvert A\rvert^{1/2}$, by Parseval's identity. The $L^\infty$ norm is always trivially $=\lvert A\rvert$ (at most by the triangle inequality, and clearly $\theta=0$ achieves this).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. $L^1$ is the hard case. For $L^2$, by Parseval you have equality. Similarly, $L^\infty$ is trivially equal to $|A|$, by evaluating the exponential sum at $0$ where there will be no cancellation. For $p>2$, at least when $p$ is an even integer, the extremal sets will be arithmetic progressions. It is conjectured that the extermal examples for Littlewood are also APs, but this is open and likely very hard.

Comment: Please always include a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory".

Comment: @Thomas Bloom,@ Mark Lewko, thanks for point out the $L^1$ norm and $L^p$ norm case, the $L_{\infty}$  case already corrected.

Comment: I don't understand the new question - in general $\sum_{a\in A}e(a\theta)$ will be a non-real complex number, so what is meant by $(\sum_{a\in A}e(a\theta))_+$?

Comment: The well-known ``cosine problem" asks for an estimate on $-\max_{x} \sum_{a \in A} \cos(ax)$, which seems to be the natural question in this direction. It isn't hard to deduce a lower bound of order $\log |A|$ using the resolution of Littlewood. However one expects the truth to be on the order of $|A|^{1/2}$. This is hard and open. Ruzsa has the current world record which is asymptotically better than using Littlewood but is still sub-polynomial.

Comment: Thomas Bloom， I am sorry, this needs to change to some projection of the complex function.